# RE2 Not matching non-ascii characters

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I cannot get RE2 to match bytes (that aren't ascii) using their hex/octal representation.

Code snippet below explains the problem:

```
char *test = "abc""\xe2""xyz";
std::string str(test); // "abc\342xyz" . \342 is octal for \xe2
// str.size() == 7

re2::StringPiece string_piece(str); // size is 7, as expected

std::string out;

// extracts the letter 'z' into 'out;. \172 is the octal for z
bool match = re2::RE2::PartialMatch(string_piece, ("(\172)"), &out); // match = true, out = 'z'.

// should extract the character \342...but it doesn't.
match = re2::RE2::PartialMatch(string_piece, ("(\342)"), &out); // match = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the encoding to latin-1 - RE2 default is UTF-8

```
match = re2::RE2::PartialMatch(string_piece,
          re2::RE2("(\342)", re2::RE2::Latin1),
          &out);
```